# Use Elastic Search to store data values sent by IOT devices in a period of time

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch, iot

Escenario:

- Many many devices
- Each devices sent values each few seconds
- Want to store the values sent

I can use mongo with time series collections (https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/timeseries-collections/), but this needs a big mongo database, as the objetive to store this values is only save an read, dont modify that values and use them like historic data, i have thought use Elastic Search, for example, take a VPS put Elastic on it with big disk space (dedicated mongo is expensive than this option).

Mongo vs Elastic in this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO, Elasticsearch seems to be a better choice due to below reason, I don't know if same is available in mongoDB.

1. As you have a timeseries data, you can easily rollover your indices using the [index lifecycle management](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-lifecycle-management.html), that saves your cost as well, as after sometime(according to your use-case), you can move your data to cheaper storage or even delete them automatically.
2. You can also visualise your data stored in Elasticsearch using Kibana.

Comment: I already use Elastic for logs, do you recommend to get two differents machines with Elastic, one to log and another one to message values?? To send values to the Elastic I can use filebeats or API REST, i think that is better use filebeat (100 values per seconds por example)

Comment: @dlopezgonzalez, thats great you already have familiarity with Elasticsearch, I think you can directly use API, if you don't want to maintain another infra(fikebeat) as 100 qps is really not that high.. and you can have a single Elasticsearch cluster or you can have another if you want to divide logically.. all these choices are dependant on your use-cases and trade-offs

Comment: @dlopezgonzalez would be great if you can mark answer or let me know if you have anything else to follow